# How can I return an unauthorized result from a custom attribute?

Tags: hotchocolate

I'm trying to implement a custom authorization attribute with HotChocolate.

What I have so far is this

```
namespace GraphQL.Attributes
{
    public class AuthorizeAttribute : ObjectFieldDescriptorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnConfigure(IDescriptorContext context, IObjectFieldDescriptor descriptor, MemberInfo member)
        {
            var httpContextAccessor = context.Services.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)) as IHttpContextAccessor;

            var authorizationHeader = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            var jwtService = context.Services.GetService(typeof(JwtService)) as JwtService;

            var isValidToken = jwtService.ValidateSessionToken(authorizationHeader);

            if (isValidToken == false)
            {
                // Here I want to return an Unauthorized message to the client and abort any further execution
            }

            // Everything OK
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET 5 I can do it like this

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
            var httpContextAccessor = context.Services.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)) as IHttpContextAccessor;

            var authorizationHeader = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            var jwtService = context.Services.GetService(typeof(JwtService)) as JwtService;

            var isValidToken = jwtService.ValidateSessionToken(authorizationHeader);

            if (isValidToken == false)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(new
                {
                    Code = 1,
                    Message = "Invalid token"
                });

                return;
            }

            // Everything OK
            return;
    }
}
```

As you can see, In ASP.NET we can set an `UnauthorizedObjectResult` as the result and the API would return that.

How can I return an unauthorized result from my custom attribute in HotChocolate?

I guess I should use any of `IDescriptorContext`, `IObjectFieldDescriptor` or `MemberInfo`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe throw GraphQLException?  You can add quite a bit of customization in there.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this :

```
public class MyAuthorizationHandler : HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationHandler
{
    public async ValueTask<AuthorizeResult> AuthorizeAsync(IMiddlewareContext context, AuthorizeDirective directive)
    {
        var authorizeResult = AuthorizeResult.NotAllowed;


        var httpContextAccessor = context.Services.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)) as IHttpContextAccessor;

        var authorizationHeader = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

        var jwtService = context.Services.GetService(typeof(JwtService)) as JwtService;

        var isValidToken = jwtService.ValidateSessionToken(authorizationHeader);

        if (isValidToken)
        {
            authorizeResult = AuthorizeResult.Allowed;
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(((Func<AuthorizeResult>)(() =>
        {
            return authorizeResult;

        }))());
    }
```

---

```
        services.AddGraphQLServer()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddQueryType<IQueryForms>()
            .AddAuthorization();

        services.AddGraphQLServer().AddSocketSessionInterceptor<AuthenticationSocketInterceptor>();
        services.AddSingleton<HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthorizationHandler>();
```